# How to solve this error in MS word, because I am getting an error everytime I try to adjust my table in Microsoft word

Tags: microsoft-word

> run-time error 6197: This object model command is not available while in the current event.

[image]

[Document sample](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QuQkpk8mr6OalGuMiagSttgmngH4SJuf/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: There is some VBA code which produces this error. If it is not relative to a file, then check for macro correctness (if exists) in normal and another dot/dotx/dotm files loaded, and look for add-ons and disable them one-by-one for to find a problematic one...

Comment: Better post the document to be examined.

Comment: I have added the doc above please have a look.

Regarding the VBA code, I have not added any!.

Comment: @harrymc please have a look at the file, I uploaded it in the "hyperlink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really appreciate everyone’s shot.

I guess I was encountering an issue with some of my add-ons in word. When I disabled  some of them the doc works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded your document and saw that it does not contain any VBA.
In addition, this error does not arrive on my computer.

The problem must come from a change that you have made to the template file.
Unless you have created a new template, the default template is found in the file(s)
named `Normal.dot` and/or `Normal.dotm`. These templates are used for all documents
by default.

If you have not done any intentional modifications to these files, you can
re-create them with their defaults as follows:

- Close all Office applications
- Browse to the folder
  `C:\Users\<user-name>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates`
- Rename the file(s) `Normal.dot` and `Normal.dotm` so as to be able to undo
  the change (it's ok if only one file is found)
- Launch Word to create the new template.

To avoid unintended modifications of the template in the future, set the
option to prompt before modifying it, as follows:

- Open the ribbon *File > Options*
- Go to the Advanced section
- Under Save, place a check-mark on "Prompt before saving Normal template"
- Click OK.

Comment: Thanks for your concern, I have already gained the answer, I will post it down here.